# Retrieving information from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

Im trying to retrieve information from my firebase. Heres what the data looks [image: like].

Every time i run this i receive null in the log.

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://sizzling-inferno-255.firebaseio.com/"];
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"date_of_birth"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value[@"full_name"]);
}];
```

I want the app to check if the name of the table is info and if so load the date of birth and full name. How can i do this?

Comment: how did you define the variable ref ?

Comment: @ArunGJ updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are observing changes to changes in database, instead of fetching records. Moreover, you haven't defined reference url `users` against which you want to fetch data. Try this:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://sizzling-inferno-255.firebaseio.com/"];

//Refer to users entity
Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath: @"users"];

// Read data and react to changes
[usersRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", snapshot.key, snapshot.value);
}];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it does thank you but if i were to just grab the info from the date_of_birth field and full_name field how would i do that.

Answer (score 1):

The root object of your data is `users`. You have to iterate through the data to get to info. Use can code something like below.

```
NSDictionary *info = snapshot.value[@"info"];
NSString *dob = info[@"date_of_birth"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `[ref child:@"users/info"]` just before `observeEventType` child because you are just accessing the child one step below the root which is just "users" you aren't actually getting down to date of birth and full name.

Comment: thanks for that and i understand what you mean but how would i add [ref child:@"users/info"]